# returning functions vs void functions setting variables

Tags: c#

New programmer here, I just wondered about this for a while. Take a look at this for instance, what is the difference between these ?:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program obj = new Program();
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(obj.Add()));
}
int Add()
{
    return 1 + 1;
}
```

and

```
int Sum;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Sum));
}

void Add()
{
    Sum = 1+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first case executes the method `Add` and prints the return value `2` to the console.

The second case will not compile because `Sum` is a class variable and you are missing a object reference like in the first case to access it.

If you would make `Sum` `static` then your `Main` will work and print simply the default value of `Sum` which is `0`. Since you never call the `Add` method.

As for the difference of the two `Add()` methods:
The second case uses a class variable and manipulates it. It has to be called so that the value of `Sum` changes.

The first case uses only a local computation and does not change anything within the class. It simply returns the result of a calculation

EDIT:

> What would be the difference between the two, which will be preferable?

It depends strongly on what you intend to do. If the only thing you are interested is the result of `1+1` and you need to use this result in some method like the `Main` then use the first case.

If the variable represents a significant feature of the class like this:

```
public class BillsToPay
{
    public int Sum;

    List<int> Bills = new List<int>() {3,5,6,7};

    public void CalculateAllBills()
    {
        foreach (var bill in Bills)
        {
            Sum = Sum + bill;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would have a method which manipulates the class variable `Sum` and updates its state. so the second version kicks in. But it is always a mixture of taste and intention of how to approach a given problem.

Small test program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{       
    BillsToPay btp = new BillsToPay();      
    btp.CalculateAllBills();        
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(btp.Sum));       
}
```

Comment: I see. So this:
`
    
    int Sum;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        void Add();
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Sum));
    }

    void Add()
    {
    Sum = 1+1;
    }
    `

Should return 2? Apologize for the rather stupid question

Comment: @MatthysFourie I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Ah yes I just wrote the code in notepad, my compiler should have picked that up. Another question, how do you make code work in comments, if you can at all? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: @MatthysFourie "make code work in comments" ? I don't quite understand.. if you put `//` in front of code it will not be executed.

Comment: You put a backtick (`) before and after code if you want it formatted in the comments section

Comment: @MatthysFourie Ahhh in comments here on SO ?=! :) sorry did not get that. Make sure that there are no spaces between the backtick and the next character or the previous character

Comment: @Mong Thanks, so if I fix the second one and say `int Sum;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program obj = new Program();
            obj.Add();
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(obj.Sum));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        void Add()
        {
            Sum = 1 + 1;
        }`

What would be the difference between the two, which will be preferable?

Comment: @MatthysFourie welcome to stack overflow if you found my answer helpful, I would appreciate if you could [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).